# How do you access/pull data from an outside server into a Docker container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ssh-keys

I have run into more and more data scientists who use Docker containers, in order to allow for reproducible analyses.

Question: How do you download/pull data into a Docker container?

If the data is downloadable via a URL, naturally you could add a line like this in the Dockerfile

```
wget www.server_to_data.org/path/path/myfile.gz
```

But I have data sitting on a server, whereby users `ssh` into the server with a key-pair in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. I'm not sure how this could work security-wise.

How does one normally download or access your data in this case?

One could possible mount the server, but I'm not sure how one accesses these within the Container/VM.

Comment: If your data requires credentials for access -- particularly interactive login credentials -- then it's not clear that it allows for reproducible analysis.  I mean, someone from outside of your institution isn't going to have the necessary credentials to access the data.  If your institution doesn't have an established mechanism for exposing research datasets to outside users, you'll probably need to address that first.

Comment: Having said that, one can expose a private key to a container using a bind mount (`docker run -v $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa:/root/.ssh/id_rsa ...`), or the key data can be passed in as an environment variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your current situation, where you've got the data on a server, and you're handing out key pairs to people who should have access.  If you want to just use that existing infrastructure without changing it.  Could be done by setting a volume for the ssh keys in the image and then people running the image would need to start the container with the volume set to their ssh key.

Set a volume in the image with the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu 
#[RUN your installation process]
VOLUME /home/container_user/.ssh
```

Run the container with mounting the location of the ssh key to that volume:

```
docker run -d -v PATH_TO_DRECITORY_HOLDING_SSH_KEY:/home/container_user/.ssh [OTHER OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]
```

Then you can download the data as part of the script that runs when the container is started.

The basic idea is lifted from [How can I get my ~/.ssh keys into a docker container running locally?](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-get-my-ssh-keys-into-a-docker-container-running-locally)

That said, if we back the question up a little and ask how exactly people are going to be using your image, where the image is going to be stored (public or private repo) and how often the data changes there may be some more user friendly ways to satisfy the need. Also if you allow for docker-compose to be the means by which the container is run there is some other options available to you.

Comment: You don't _need_ to set a VOLUME in the Dockerfile in order to use a volume at runtime. You probably don't need an implicit anonymous volume at this location, so the Dockerfile change is probably not necessary.

Comment: @JeffRichards "If you want to just use that existing infrastructure without changing it." Let's say I have a python algorithm I would like users to run on this data. I'm used to writing Dockerfiles whereby I install Linux, python, all python libraries, etc. from scratch. Is it possible that the Docker container could inherit our current version of the software and run this?

Comment: @JeffRichards " Also if you allow for docker-compose to be the means by which the container is run there is some other options available to you" Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: @EB2127 The word inherit is a bit ambiguous for me.  But if your software is in a source control repository (is git), you could certainly clone/pull that repo as part of your build process, or as part of the run script if you wanted it to be updated everytime the container was run.  If your software is not in a git repo, you can still copy that into the image so that it is part and parcel of the image.